# Arduino_Visual_Studio-Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-ide

I have an windows form application that was created in `visual studio 2013`. how can i run the `.exe` file on my arduino or on `raspberry PI`??

Has anyone tried this?

Any information will be helpful

Comment: As far as the arduino, this is completely impossible.  The Raspberry Pi you may be able to run some things with Mono (I haven't tried) but it's probably not going to do it well enough to bother.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not feasible or practical to attempt a Windows Form application on a Raspberry Pi and definitely an impossibility on an Arduino.

The RaspberryPi.org site explicitly states that RaspberryPi will not run Windows applications: [enter link description here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs)

The Arduino really does not have a GUI or a Window subsystem that would support that type of application. Really, the Arduino is just such a tiny little 8 bit cpu, 2k ram computer, it is just **completely off the radar** for a Windows application.

You may want to investigate the possibility of writing a Python application in windows and porting that to a Raspberry Pi.